# Problem in drawing line of negative slope of Mid point line algorithm using gl opener

Tags: python

I can draw lines of positive slope very easily using this algorithm d=2dy-dx; if d>0 then d=d+2dy-2dx else d=d+2dy till the co ordinates x and y equals to the final co ordinates. As it is not useful for negative slope so I take help from the net and wrote this for the given co ordinates and this also not helping.

```
    x1=200
    y1=400
    x2=350
    y2=200
    dx=x2-x1
    dy=y2-y1 //difference of the starting co ordinate and the destination co ordinate
    y3=1
    y=0
    if(dy<0):
        y3=-1
        dy=-dy
    else:
        d=(2*dy)-dx
        y=y1    
    
    for x in range(x1,x2):
        glVertex2d(x,y)
        if(d>0):
            y=y+y3
            d=d+(2*(dy-dx))
        else:
            d=d+2*dy
```

Comment: Why did you use a c-like `//` comment here? Python uses `#` for comments

Comment: What do you expect that won't happen? What does not work?